# C++ last character in file

Tags: c++, file, char

I would like to get the last character in file using the following code

```
 FILE * f = fopen ( f_text, "r" );
 if (f )
 {
    if (fseek( f, -1, SEEK_END ) != 0 ) fclose (f);
    char last[1]; 
    fgets(last, 1, f );
    ...
```

but only "" is stored in variable last. Where is the bug?

Is there any problem with unicode files? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is a proper text file, wouldn't the last character be `\n`?

Comment: This code does not compile, because you are missing a `)` before `fclose(f);`

Comment: @user315052: No, why should that be the case?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It can be an indication of an inadvertently truncated text file. For example, your text editor crashed.

Comment: @user315052: It can be, but one is perfectly capable of saving a text file without a trailing new line character.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: A text file is by definition line oriented data. It [would cause problems when working with text file tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline) if the last line did not look like all the other lines.

Comment: @user315052 If it's a proper text file, the `fseek` is illegal.  (I forget whether it is undefined behavior, or the function should return an error.  The former, I suspect, so that implementations under Unix can make it work.)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley If the last character output to a file opened in text mode is not a `'\n'`, the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You're right, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `fgets` will form a string. Since you only gave it one byte to work with, it can only return you an empty string, since it needs that byte to store the `'\0'`.

As James Kanze pointed out to me, you can only use `fseek` the way you want portably if you have opened the file in binary mode. Since the file is now in binary mode, it would be inappropriate to use `fgets`. So you would use `fread` instead.

```
FILE *f = fopen(f_text, "rb");
if (f == 0) throw 0;
try {
    if (fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END) != 0) throw 0;
    char last[1];
    if (fread(last, 1, 1, f) != 1) throw 0;
    //...
}
catch (...) {
    fclose(f);
    throw;
}
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fgetc` instead of `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code to print the last character. Here is test.c as a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE * f;
    char * f_text = "temp.txt";

    f = fopen ( f_text, "r" );
    if (f )
    {

        if (fseek( f, -2, SEEK_END ) == 0 ) 
        {
            char last[2] = {0}; 
            printf("Got here.\n");
            last[0] = fgetc( f );
            printf("%s\n", last);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here is temp.txt displayed at the command line.

```
octopusgrabbus@steamboy:~/scratch$ cat temp.txt
This is a test.
octopusgrabbus@steamboy:~/scratch$
```

I changed your fseek to seek two from the end, so test would print the period.
As another answer indicated, I used fgetc instead of fgets, because you were 
looking for an individual character, not a full string.

I also changed last to last[2] and initialized to zero, so I could treat
the last character as a zero-terminated string for demo purposes.